# MVC2 Editor templates not using datetime format

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-2, date

Following on from an earlier question, I'm having problems using an Editor template for datetime fields, below is the code for the editor template (called "EditDateTime").

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>

<%= Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") : 
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")), new { @class = "date" })%>
```

Here is the call to use the editor template,

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.StartDate, "EditDateTime") %>
```

All works ok, except the formatting is ignored. The Asp.Net MVC2 Framework book documents templates and specifically states

> We’re passing an empty string for the name
>   parameter because the framework will automatically prefix this with the field name corresponding to the model item being rendered;

So I shouldnt need an id, so why is the formatting being ignored? HOWEVER - if I include an ID, the formatting is adhered to, BUT the model binding is then broken.

Help?

---

Just to clarify..
If I give the HMTL.Textbox an ID I get the following... The date format is correct but I lose the model binding as the ID is changed from "StartDate" to "StartDate_xx"

```
<input class="date" id="StartDate_xx" name="StartDate.xx" type="text" value="02/May/2012" />
```

And without the Id, it looks like this... model binding is correct but format is not.

```
<input class="date" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="text" value="05/02/2012 00:00:00" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

works for me.

everything looks fine really... is the item you are sending a `Datetime` or a `Datetime?`

Comment: This doesnt work - it has to be an editor template not a display template. Thank you very much for you help though.